# Huge amount of unloaded LambdaForm classes when using Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I'm building a framework which invokes custom Nashorn scripts which in turn registers Predicates, Comparators etc.

Ie.

```
function init (context)
{
  context.registerFilter("name", function(item) {
    ... Do some filter of item
  });
}
```

Then on the Java side I make use of the registered filters. When doing this for a lot of items a long time i'm seeing HUGE amount of unloaded classes of type **java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH/BMH**
Is this normal, should I be worried to take this into production ?

[image]

I've tried different JVM's (1.8 u152, u161, u162) all with the same behavior.

Comment: If they're unloaded why do you care?

Comment: That's why I'm asking, is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nashorn generates invokedynamic instruction for every method call, property set/get from JS. LambdaForms are generated by JDK to handle those invokedynamic instructions. You mentioned that those classes are unloaded. Unless you see serious performance problems, you have nothing to worry.

Comment: Thanks, I ran a quite heavy and long test and saw no leaks etc. so I guess this is normal. This was my first encounter with invokedynamic and have better understanding of the internals.